# Error running jupyterhub on Redhat 6.7

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to run jupyterhub on a RedHat 6.7 system. I can start jupyterhub, use my browser to authenticate. I can also select to start a new Python 3 notebook, but I can't execute commands in it, because there are errors on server side. See the log from jupyterhub below.

My setup:

- RedHat 6.7
- python 3.4
- ipython 4.0.0
- notebook 4.0.4
- jupyterhub 0.2.0
- nodejs 0.10.36

Any help greatly appreciated!
Mike M

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" jupyterhub

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:02.796 JupyterHub app:518] Loading cookie_secret from /usr/src/jupyterhub_cookie_secret

[W 2015-08-25 17:27:02.867 JupyterHub app:257] 
    Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
    Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message.

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:02.878 JupyterHub app:654] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:02.900 JupyterHub app:1032] Hub API listening on ...

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:02.916 JupyterHub app:789] Starting proxy @ http://*:8000/
17:27:03.195 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to ...
17:27:03.201 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at ...

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:03.254 JupyterHub app:1055] JupyterHub is now running at ...

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:07.775 JupyterHub log:100] 302 GET / (@10.128.0.253) 4.31ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:07.781 JupyterHub log:100] 302 GET /hub (@10.128.0.253) 0.56ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:07.798 JupyterHub log:100] 302 GET /hub/ (mikem@10.128.0.253) 5.76ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:07.856 JupyterHub log:100] 200 GET /hub/home (mikem@10.128.0.253) 48.21ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:13.412 JupyterHub login:17] User logged out: mikem

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:13.421 JupyterHub log:100] 302 GET /hub/logout (mikem@10.128.0.253) 8.17ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:13.436 JupyterHub log:100] 200 GET /hub/ (@10.128.0.253) 11.13ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:21.463 JupyterHub spawner:365] Spawning jupyterhub-singleuser --user=mikem --port=44634 --cookie-name=jupyter-hub-token-mikem --base-url=/user/mikem --hub-prefix=/hub/ --hub-api-url=... --ip=localhost
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
  warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html.py:14: ShimWarning: The `IPython.html` package has been deprecated. You should import from `notebook` instead. `IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`.
  "`IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`.", ShimWarning)

[W 2015-08-25 17:27:22.712 mikem notebookapp:252] ipywidgets package not installed.  Widgets are unavailable.

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.745 mikem notebookapp:1061] Serving notebooks from local directory: /nfshome/mikem

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.746 mikem notebookapp:1061] 0 active kernels 

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.746 mikem notebookapp:1061] The IPython Notebook is running at: ...

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.746 mikem notebookapp:1062] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.871 JupyterHub base:277] User mikem server took 1.523 seconds to start

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.872 JupyterHub orm:170] Adding user mikem to proxy /user/mikem => ...

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.876 mikem log:47] 302 GET /user/mikem (127.0.0.1) 7.75ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.896 JupyterHub log:100] 302 POST /hub/login?next= (@10.128.0.253) 3388.59ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.896 JupyterHub login:76] User logged in: mikem

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.913 JupyterHub log:100] 302 GET /hub/ (mikem@10.128.0.253) 6.54ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.924 mikem log:47] 302 GET /user/mikem (10.128.0.253) 1.56ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:22.982 JupyterHub log:100] 200 GET /hub/api/authorizations/cookie/jupyter-hub-token-mikem/[secret] (mikem@127.0.0.1) 15.09ms

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:38.124 mikem handlers:175] Creating new notebook in 

[W 2015-08-25 17:27:38.767 mikem log:47] 404 GET /user/mikem/nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20150825172722 (10.128.0.253) 15.28ms referer=...
Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python3

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:39.014 mikem kernelmanager:85] Kernel started: 2ca52dbf-ae67-4f40-b800-fe7f5b73da56
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/runpy.py in _run_module_as_main(mod_name='ipykernel.__main__', alter_argv=1)
    168         sys.argv[0] = mod_spec.origin
    169     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
--> 170                      "__main__", mod_spec)
        mod_spec = ModuleSpec(name='ipykernel.__main__', loader=<_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fa8917636a0>, origin='/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py')
    171 
    172 def run_module(mod_name, init_globals=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/runpy.py in _run_code(code=<code object <module> at 0x7fa8917ece40, file "/...3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 1>, run_globals={'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__cached__': '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__pycache__/__main__.cpython-34.pyc', '__doc__': None, '__file__': '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object>, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': 'ipykernel', '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='ipykernel.__main__', loader=<_f...b/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py'), 'app': <module 'ipykernel.kernelapp' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py'>}, init_globals=None, mod_name='__main__', mod_spec=ModuleSpec(name='ipykernel.__main__', loader=<_f...b/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py'), pkg_name='ipykernel', script_name=None)
     83                        __package__ = pkg_name,
     84                        __spec__ = mod_spec)
---> 85     exec(code, run_globals)
        global exec = undefined
        code = <code object <module> at 0x7fa8917ece40, file "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 1>
        run_globals = {'__name__': '__main__', '__file__': '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py', '__cached__': '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__pycache__/__main__.cpython-34.pyc', 'app': <module 'ipykernel.kernelapp' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py'>, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': 'ipykernel', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fa8917636a0>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='ipykernel.__main__', loader=<_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fa8917636a0>, origin='/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py')}
     86     return run_globals
     87 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py in <module>()
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
      2     from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
----> 3     app.launch_new_instance()
        global app.launch_new_instance = <bound method MetaHasTraits.launch_instance of <class 'ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp'>>

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py in launch_instance(cls=<class 'ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp'>, argv=None, **kwargs={})
    589         """
    590         app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
--> 591         app.initialize(argv)
        app.initialize = <bound method IPKernelApp.initialize of <ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object at 0x7fa8917635c0>>
        argv = None
    592         app.start()
    593 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py in initialize(self=<ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object>, argv=None)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py in catch_config_error(method=<function IPKernelApp.initialize>, app=<ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object>, *args=(None,), **kwargs={})
     73     """
     74     try:
---> 75         return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
        method = <function IPKernelApp.initialize at 0x7fa88b21db70>
        app = <ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object at 0x7fa8917635c0>
        args = (None,)
        kwargs = {}
     76     except (TraitError, ArgumentError) as e:
     77         app.print_help()

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py in initialize(self=<ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object>, argv=None)
    369         self.init_io()
    370         self.init_signal()
--> 371         self.init_kernel()
        self.init_kernel = <bound method IPKernelApp.init_kernel of <ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object at 0x7fa8917635c0>>
    372         # shell init steps
    373         self.init_path()

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py in init_kernel(self=<ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object>)
    312                                 log=self.log,
    313                                 profile_dir=self.profile_dir,
--> 314                                 user_ns=self.user_ns,
        global user_ns = undefined
        self.user_ns = None
    315         )
    316         kernel.record_ports(self.ports)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py in instance(cls=<class 'ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel'>, *args=(), **kwargs={'iopub_socket': <zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object>, 'log': <logging.Logger object>, 'parent': <ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object>, 'profile_dir': <IPython.core.profiledir.ProfileDir object>, 'session': <jupyter_client.session.Session object>, 'shell_streams': [<zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object>, <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object>], 'stdin_socket': <zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object>, 'user_ns': None})
    378         # Create and save the instance
    379         if cls._instance is None:
--> 380             inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        inst = undefined
        cls = <class 'ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel'>
        args = ()
        kwargs = {'log': <logging.Logger object at 0x7fa891763588>, 'user_ns': None, 'parent': <ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object at 0x7fa8917635c0>, 'iopub_socket': <zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object at 0x7fa88b2156a8>, 'stdin_socket': <zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object at 0x7fa88b215708>, 'session': <jupyter_client.session.Session object at 0x7fa88b22d828>, 'profile_dir': <IPython.core.profiledir.ProfileDir object at 0x7fa88b22d470>, 'shell_streams': [<zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x7fa88b22da58>, <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x7fa88b22d9e8>]}
    381             # Now make sure that the instance will also be returned by
    382             # parent classes' _instance attribute.

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py in __init__(self=<ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object>, **kwargs={'iopub_socket': <zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object>, 'log': <logging.Logger object>, 'parent': <ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp object>, 'profile_dir': <IPython.core.profiledir.ProfileDir object>, 'session': <jupyter_client.session.Session object>, 'shell_streams': [<zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object>, <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object>], 'stdin_socket': <zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object>, 'user_ns': None})
     45             user_module = self.user_module,
     46             user_ns     = self.user_ns,
---> 47             kernel      = self,
        global kernel = undefined
        self = <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object at 0x7fa88b22dda0>
     48         )
     49         self.shell.displayhook.session = self.session

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py in instance(cls=<class 'ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell'>, *args=(), **kwargs={'kernel': <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object>, 'parent': <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object>, 'profile_dir': <IPython.core.profiledir.ProfileDir object>, 'user_module': None, 'user_ns': None})
    378         # Create and save the instance
    379         if cls._instance is None:
--> 380             inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        inst = undefined
        cls = <class 'ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell'>
        args = ()
        kwargs = {'user_module': None, 'kernel': <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object at 0x7fa88b22dda0>, 'profile_dir': <IPython.core.profiledir.ProfileDir object at 0x7fa88b22d470>, 'parent': <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object at 0x7fa88b22dda0>, 'user_ns': None}
    381             # Now make sure that the instance will also be returned by
    382             # parent classes' _instance attribute.

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in __init__(self=<ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object>, ipython_dir=None, profile_dir=<IPython.core.profiledir.ProfileDir object>, user_module=None, user_ns=None, custom_exceptions=((), None), **kwargs={'kernel': <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object>, 'parent': <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object>})
    552         self.init_data_pub()
    553         self.init_displayhook()
--> 554         self.init_magics()
        self.init_magics = <bound method ZMQInteractiveShell.init_magics of <ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object at 0x7fa88b22de10>>
    555         self.init_alias()
    556         self.init_logstart()

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py in init_magics(self=<ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object>)
    477 
    478     def init_magics(self):
--> 479         super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).init_magics()
        global super = undefined
        global ZMQInteractiveShell = <class 'ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell'>
        self.init_magics = <bound method ZMQInteractiveShell.init_magics of <ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object at 0x7fa88b22de10>>
    480         self.register_magics(KernelMagics)
    481         self.magics_manager.register_alias('ed', 'edit')

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in init_magics(self=<ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object>)
   2216         # should be split into a prompt manager and displayhook. We probably
   2217         # even need a centralize colors management object.
-> 2218         self.magic('colors %s' % self.colors)
        self.magic = <bound method ZMQInteractiveShell.magic of <ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object at 0x7fa88b22de10>>
        self.colors = 'Linux'
   2219     
   2220     # Defined here so that it's included in the documentation

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self=<ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object>, arg_s='colors Linux')
   2334         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2335         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2336         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
        self.run_line_magic = <bound method ZMQInteractiveShell.run_line_magic of <ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object at 0x7fa88b22de10>>
        magic_name = 'colors'
        magic_arg_s = 'Linux'
   2337 
   2338     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self=<ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object>, magic_name='colors', line='Linux')
   2255                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2256             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2257                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
        result = undefined
        fn = <bound method BasicMagics.colors of <IPython.core.magics.basic.BasicMagics object at 0x7fa87b5cce80>>
        args = ['Linux']
        kwargs = {}
   2258             return result
   2259 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/basic.py in colors(self=<IPython.core.magics.basic.BasicMagics object>, parameter_s='Linux')

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f=<function BasicMagics.colors>, *a=(<IPython.core.magics.basic.BasicMagics object>, 'Linux'), **k={})
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
        global call = undefined
        f = <function BasicMagics.colors at 0x7fa88ec5cbf8>
        a = (<IPython.core.magics.basic.BasicMagics object at 0x7fa87b5cce80>, 'Linux')
        k = {}
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/basic.py in colors(self=<IPython.core.magics.basic.BasicMagics object>, parameter_s='Linux')
    338         shell = self.shell
    339 
--> 340         import IPython.utils.rlineimpl as readline
        global IPython.utils.rlineimpl = undefined
        readline = undefined
    341 
    342         if not shell.colors_force and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/rlineimpl.py in <module>()
     19     try:
     20         # import readline as _rl
---> 21         _rl = __import__(_rlmod_name)
        global _rl = undefined
        global __import__ = undefined
        global _rlmod_name = 'readline'
     22         # from readline import *
     23         globals().update({k:v for k,v in _rl.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')})

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readline.py in <module>()
      4 #of a readline module
      5 from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals, absolute_import
----> 6 from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
        global pyreadline.rlmain = undefined
        global Readline = undefined
      7 
      8 __all__ = [ 'parse_and_bind',

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyreadline/__init__.py in <module>()
      9 from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals, absolute_import
     10 
---> 11 from . import unicode_helper, logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
        global unicode_helper = <module 'pyreadline.unicode_helper' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyreadline/unicode_helper.py'>
        global logger = <module 'pyreadline.logger' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyreadline/logger.py'>
        global clipboard = undefined
        global lineeditor = undefined
        global modes = undefined
        global console = undefined
     12 from .rlmain import *
     13 from . import rlmain

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/__init__.py in <module>()
     11 else:
     12     try:
---> 13         from .win32_clipboard import GetClipboardText, SetClipboardText
        global win32_clipboard = undefined
        global GetClipboardText = undefined
        global SetClipboardText = undefined
     14     except ImportError:
     15         from .no_clipboard import GetClipboardText, SetClipboardText

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/win32_clipboard.py in <module>()
     35 
     36 from ctypes import *
---> 37 from pyreadline.keysyms.winconstants import CF_UNICODETEXT, GHND
        global pyreadline.keysyms.winconstants = undefined
        global CF_UNICODETEXT = undefined
        global GHND = undefined
     38 from pyreadline.unicode_helper import ensure_unicode,ensure_str
     39 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyreadline/keysyms/__init__.py in <module>()
     21     
     22 if not success:
---> 23     raise ImportError("Could not import keysym for local pythonversion", x)
        global ImportError = undefined
        global x = undefined

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
^C
Interrupted

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:41.398 JupyterHub app:924] Cleaning up single-user servers...

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:41.403 JupyterHub app:935] Cleaning up proxy[31708]...

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:41.409 mikem notebookapp:1016] Shutting down kernels

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:41.411 mikem multikernelmanager:137] Kernel shutdown: 2ca52dbf-ae67-4f40-b800-fe7f5b73da56

[I 2015-08-25 17:27:41.716 JupyterHub app:961] ...done
```

Comment: You've somehow got pyreadline installed. That's a shim for readline on Windows, and it won't work on a Linux system. Uninstall pyreadline.

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thanks a lot Thomas!